# Running two Azure Web Apps on different subdomains of the same domain

Tags: azure-webapps

I have a multi-tenant web app where each tenant has their own subdomain -- `tenant.thing.co.uk`.

Can I set up *two* Azure Web Apps on different subdomains and move the tenant to a sub-sub domain like this:

- `tenant.app1.thing.co.uk` and
- `tenant.app2.thing.co.uk`?

In the Azure Web App under *Custom domains* I can enter `*.app1.thing.co.uk` and add `TXT` and `CNAME` records to my DNS to get the validation to pass: there is one `TXT` record and two `CNAME` records:

| Name | Data |
| --- | --- |
| app1 | thing-app.azurewebites.net |
| app2 | thing-app2.azurewebsites.net |

But it doesn't work! (Firefox says: *Server not found*.)

However, if I add one `CNAME` for `*.thing.co.uk` and add `*.app1.thing.co.uk` to one Azure Web App (and delete the other Azure Web App) then the website appears and the tenant subdomains work.

So: what's going wrong with two apps?

Comment: I'm confused:  do you want two separate applications running in different spaces, or two different subdomains for the same app?

Comment: Two separate Azure App Service resources

Answer (score 0):

Add an A Record for each subdomain pointing to the IP address of each App Service.

Comment: So I need to use `A` and not `CNAME`?

Comment: I think I've done that but still nothing. And `dig` has no `ANSWER` section and says `NXDOMAIN` for any subdomain.

Comment: Azure gives the same IP for both App Services!

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be:

In DNS:

- add a `TXT` record with name `asuid.subdomain` for each subdomain, and
- add a `CNAME` record with name `*.subdomain` and value the azure web app domain name.

In *Custom domains* for the Azure web app:

- add a custom domain `*.subdomain.domain.tld`, *and*
- add a custom domain `subdomain.domain.tld`.

So the fix for me was to add two -- not one -- custom domains in the Azure website.